# pandas text to CSV conversion: float string to number problem

Tags: python, pandas, csv, text

Trying to convert a text file with one column to a CSV file using python pandas `to_csv`.

Problem: `3761.000000`, `3760.978027`, etc. (`.` represents decimal point) gets converted to `3.761.000.000`, `3.760.978.027`, etc (whole numbers)...

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open your CSV as a txt file what do you get?

Using Excel it can be a problem of your default settings (separator and float format).

Use the parameters `sep` to set the column separators and `decimal` for the decimal number's separator.

For example:

```py
df.to_csv('some/path/file.csv', sep=',', decimal='.')
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html